# C# fill in tp-link login pop-up window

Tags: c#, authentication, popup

I need to parse html code of tp-link router control panel page (tplinklogin.net)in order to get traffic statistics. The problem is that I can't parse the html until authentication in pop-up window is done. How do I fill this form and press "Log In" using C# so then I could parse the html?

Comment: Flagging as too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [webBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) object, I am using google as an example here .

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
```

Next you will use ID to get elements and can call events as follows

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id").InvokeMember("click");
```